# Type error: Cannot read property currentTime of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, video.js

I am using Videojs in my react application. I am trying to set the current time of videojs player. But I am getting error saying "cannot read property currentTime of undefined". Here is how I am trying to do

```
var player;

class DummyPlayer extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
        player: {},
        tags: [{
            category: "Compliance",
            stopTime: 10,
            text: "Car",
            time: 0
        }]
    };
    }


    componentDidMount = ()=> {
        this.init()
    }

    init = ()=> {
        this.initVideoJS()
    }


    initVideoJS = ()=> {
        debug('Init VideoJS')
        const options = {
            fluid: true,
            preload: false,
            autoplay: false,
            controls: true,
            aspectRatio: "16:9"
        }

        player = this.video = videojs(this.video_el, options)

        this.setState({player:player})
        player.on("timeupdate", () => {
            currentTime = player.currentTime();

        });

    }

    jumpToSpecificMarker(time) {
        console.log("inside jump")
        player.currentTime()    // this is where I am getting error
    }
```

I am getting error in accessing currentTime from jumpToSpecificMarker method.

I also tried doing it like this

```
jumpToSpecificMarker(time) {
            console.log("inside jump")
            this.state.player.currentTime()    // this is where I am getting error
        }
```

This give me error saying "this.state.player.currentTime()" is not a function

Answer (score 0):

## The Class is scoped

You cant you a var from outside the class. In this case `player is declared outside the class.

So if you need to have a class variable add it like `this.variable` in the constructor or as a state object like you have in the constructor already. Or if this variable needs to come from an external source bring it in by declaring a `prop` in a parent component.

Comment: I tried setting the state like this.setState({player:player})  in "initVideoJS" and the tried to access currentTime like "this.state.player.currentTime()" in jumpToSpeceficMarker. But that too didn't work. WHy?

Comment: are you import in it like `import player from 'initVideoJS'` or whatever the package name is

Comment: Everything is in the single code only. Please see my code. I don't need to import anything from outside.

Answer (score 0):

Use arrow function for `jumpToSpecificMarker` method so that it can keep the scope of `this`

```
jumpToSpecificMarker = (time) => {
        console.log("inside jump")
        this.state.player.currentTime()    // this is where I am getting error
    }
```

Comment: _this.state.player.currentTime is not a function still getting this error

Comment: @ApurvG Where you are calllilng `jumpToSpecificMarker` method?

Comment: In the render method. I check for a condition inside render method and if that condition is true then I call jumpToSpecificMarker

Comment: Instead of `console.log("inside jump")` put `console.log(this.state.player)` and see if this is a blank object or it has property.

Comment: It has all the properties of player

Comment: @ApurvG You are accessing `currentTime` function in `player.on("timeupdate", () => {` too. Are you able to access `currentTime` there?

Comment: @ApurvG It seems llike your `videojs` library is adding `currentTime` function to your player object after sometime. If that is the case then you have to make sure that you call `this.state.player.currentTime()` after `currentTime` function is available.